# npm install stucked at postinstall: sill install executeActions forever

Tags: npm, post-install

I input `npm install` on the VS code terminal on Docker, and it ran and ran until `postinstall: sill install excuteActions`, and it stopped. Forever. 
[image]
I wonder what the problem is? I clicked ctrl+c afterwards to quit, but even that doesn't quit properly to return me to the cleared terminal.

Comment: Same over here. I'm trying to `make` the [mattermost-plugin-starter-template](https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-plugin-starter-template) after starting up the Go remote development container and installing newest nodejs and npm on it...

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue on my windows machine. Apparently It was permissions issue with command prompt. When I ran command prompt with administrator permissions, my problem was solved